# Converting TZNTSTMPL long timestamp to TZNTSTMPS short timestamp?

Tags: timestamp, abap, opensql, cds

In my CDS view, I'm required to Convert the Long timestamp (TZNTSTMPL) field to the Short timestamp(TZNTSTMPS).

This conversion will help in **Filtering** the data using date and time.

If we have Milli/Nanoseconds, it will not fetch the records for the given date and time.

Comment: So, you're required to remove "Milli/Nanoseconds", but what is your question?

Comment: If I can convert the Long timestamp to a Short timestamp, it would automatically remove the Milli/Nanoseconds. My question is how to convert it to a Short timestamp in the CDS?

Comment: When querying by time, then it is usually a good idea to query a from-to range instead of an exact timestamp.

Answer (score 2):

Doesn't simple CASTing help?

Given following table

```
@AbapCatalog.enhancement.category : #NOT_EXTENSIBLE
@AbapCatalog.tableCategory : #TRANSPARENT
@AbapCatalog.deliveryClass : #A
@AbapCatalog.dataMaintenance : #RESTRICTED
define table ztimestamp {
  key client      : abap.clnt not null;
  key short_stamp : tzntstmps not null;
  key long_stamp  : tzntstmpl not null;
}
```

and such CDS view

```
define view zcds_stamp as select from ztimestamp {
  key short_stamp as shorts,
      long_stamp  as longs,
      cast( long_stamp as tzntstmps ) as shorted
}
```

it produces me the identical values between `shorted` and `shorts` columns

[image]

and that's obvious because timestamp is a simple P-typed column, simple truncation should work.